# How to work with sessions in Angularjs and Laravel applications

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, session

Basically, in general web application with php we used to check session through calling php script in that particular html page.

But as I am working in Integration of application i.e. Angularjs and Laravel, I m not getting how can I achieve above said thing in this application.

Please guide me for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sessions are handled by Laravel automatically. The session data is stored in cookies. It doesn't depend on your JS framework

Comment: So, if I would like to check that if user logs in or not through session, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are handled by Laravel automatically. The session data is stored in cookies. It doesn't depend on your JS framework

If you want to check if the User has logged in, use this:

```
if (\Auth::check())
{
    // The user is logged in...
}
```

Comment: does I need to include any auth file through command promt or Just put the above code? @Paras

Comment: If you haven't already included your authentication files, just run `php artisan make:auth` to generate the login/forget password/reset password/logout views, routes and controllers. Then you may use the code in my post as is anywhere

Comment: ok means I just need to generate auth file and then include your code in my controller? Am I RIGHT? @Paras